# VMWare kernel module updater fails

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vmware-workstation, kernel-module

I'm trying to launch VMWare workstation on ubuntu 12.04 LTS. When i launch it, it says "Before you can run VMware, several modules must be compiled and loaded into the running kernel", if i hit install, it can't install Virtual Network Device and VMware Blocking Filesystem.

Screenshots:

[image: Screen 1]
[image: Screen 2]

The log:

```
2013-06-27T13:23:37.480+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Log for VMware Workstation pid=4157 version=8.0.4 build=build-744019 option=Release
2013-06-27T13:23:37.480+01:00| vthread-3| I120: The process is 64-bit.
2013-06-27T13:23:37.480+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Host codepage=UTF-8 encoding=UTF-8
2013-06-27T13:23:37.480+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Host is Linux 3.5.0-34-generic Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS
2013-06-27T13:23:37.480+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Msg_Reset:
2013-06-27T13:23:37.480+01:00| vthread-3| I120: [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/usr/lib/vmware/settings": File or directory not found.
2013-06-27T13:23:37.480+01:00| vthread-3| I120: ----------------------------------------
2013-06-27T13:23:37.480+01:00| vthread-3| I120: PREF Optional preferences file not found at /usr/lib/vmware/settings. Using default values.
2013-06-27T13:23:37.480+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Msg_Reset:
2013-06-27T13:23:37.480+01:00| vthread-3| I120: [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/root/.vmware/config": File or directory not found.
2013-06-27T13:23:37.480+01:00| vthread-3| I120: ----------------------------------------
2013-06-27T13:23:37.480+01:00| vthread-3| I120: PREF Optional preferences file not found at /root/.vmware/config. Using default values.
2013-06-27T13:23:37.480+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Msg_Reset:
2013-06-27T13:23:37.480+01:00| vthread-3| I120: [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/root/.vmware/preferences": File or directory not found.
2013-06-27T13:23:37.480+01:00| vthread-3| I120: ----------------------------------------
2013-06-27T13:23:37.480+01:00| vthread-3| I120: PREF Failed to load user preferences.
2013-06-27T13:23:37.480+01:00| vthread-3| W110: Logging to /tmp/vmware-root/modconfig-4157.log
2013-06-27T13:23:37.552+01:00| vthread-3| I120: modconf query interface initialized
2013-06-27T13:23:37.552+01:00| vthread-3| I120: modconf library initialized
2013-06-27T13:23:37.584+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2013-06-27T13:23:37.587+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/preferred/build/include for kernel release 3.5.0-34-generic
2013-06-27T13:23:37.587+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/preferred/build/include/linux/version.h
2013-06-27T13:23:37.587+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Failed version test: /lib/modules/preferred/build/include/linux/version.h not found.
2013-06-27T13:23:37.587+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/3.5.0-34-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.5.0-34-generic
2013-06-27T13:23:37.590+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2013-06-27T13:23:37.601+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2013-06-27T13:23:37.615+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Header path /lib/modules/3.5.0-34-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.5.0-34-generic is valid.
2013-06-27T13:23:37.615+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/3.5.0-34-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.5.0-34-generic
2013-06-27T13:23:37.618+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2013-06-27T13:23:37.629+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2013-06-27T13:23:37.643+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Header path /lib/modules/3.5.0-34-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.5.0-34-generic is valid.
2013-06-27T13:23:37.668+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.5.0-34-generic.
2013-06-27T13:23:37.671+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.5.0-34-generic.
2013-06-27T13:23:37.673+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.5.0-34-generic.
2013-06-27T13:23:37.674+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.5.0-34-generic.
2013-06-27T13:23:37.675+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.5.0-34-generic.
2013-06-27T13:23:37.695+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.5.0-34-generic.
2013-06-27T13:23:37.698+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.5.0-34-generic.
2013-06-27T13:23:37.701+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.5.0-34-generic.
2013-06-27T13:23:37.705+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.5.0-34-generic.
2013-06-27T13:23:37.708+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.5.0-34-generic.
2013-06-27T13:23:37.710+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/preferred/build/include for kernel release 3.5.0-34-generic
2013-06-27T13:23:37.710+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/preferred/build/include/linux/version.h
2013-06-27T13:23:37.710+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Failed version test: /lib/modules/preferred/build/include/linux/version.h not found.
2013-06-27T13:23:37.710+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/3.5.0-34-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.5.0-34-generic
2013-06-27T13:23:37.713+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2013-06-27T13:23:37.723+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2013-06-27T13:23:37.737+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Header path /lib/modules/3.5.0-34-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.5.0-34-generic is valid.
2013-06-27T13:23:37.763+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.5.0-34-generic.
2013-06-27T13:23:37.767+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.5.0-34-generic.
2013-06-27T13:23:37.768+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.5.0-34-generic.
2013-06-27T13:23:37.770+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.5.0-34-generic.
2013-06-27T13:23:37.771+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.5.0-34-generic.
2013-06-27T13:23:37.773+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/preferred/build/include for kernel release 3.5.0-34-generic
2013-06-27T13:23:37.773+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/preferred/build/include/linux/version.h
2013-06-27T13:23:37.773+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Failed version test: /lib/modules/preferred/build/include/linux/version.h not found.
2013-06-27T13:23:37.773+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/3.5.0-34-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.5.0-34-generic
2013-06-27T13:23:37.776+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2013-06-27T13:23:37.786+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2013-06-27T13:23:37.800+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Header path /lib/modules/3.5.0-34-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.5.0-34-generic is valid.
2013-06-27T13:23:37.842+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.5.0-34-generic.
2013-06-27T13:23:37.846+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.5.0-34-generic.
2013-06-27T13:23:37.849+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.5.0-34-generic.
2013-06-27T13:23:37.852+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.5.0-34-generic.
2013-06-27T13:23:37.853+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.5.0-34-generic.
2013-06-27T13:23:38.243+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.5.0-34-generic.
2013-06-27T13:23:38.243+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/3.5.0-34-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.5.0-34-generic
2013-06-27T13:23:38.246+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2013-06-27T13:23:38.252+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2013-06-27T13:23:38.259+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Header path /lib/modules/3.5.0-34-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.5.0-34-generic is valid.
2013-06-27T13:23:38.259+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module vmmon.
2013-06-27T13:23:38.274+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Extracting the sources of the vmmon module.
2013-06-27T13:23:38.326+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module with command: /usr/bin/make -j -C /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only auto-build SUPPORT_SMP=1 HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/3.5.0-34-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc GREP=/usr/bin/make IS_GCC_3=no VMCCVER=4.6
2013-06-27T13:23:43.342+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Installing module vmmon from /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon.o to /lib/modules/3.5.0-34-generic/misc.
2013-06-27T13:23:43.368+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Registering file: /usr/lib/vmware-installer/2.0/vmware-installer --register-file vmware-vmx regular /lib/modules/3.5.0-34-generic/misc/vmmon.ko
2013-06-27T13:24:02.634+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.5.0-34-generic.
2013-06-27T13:24:02.634+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/3.5.0-34-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.5.0-34-generic
2013-06-27T13:24:02.637+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2013-06-27T13:24:02.649+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2013-06-27T13:24:02.664+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Header path /lib/modules/3.5.0-34-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.5.0-34-generic is valid.
2013-06-27T13:24:02.664+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module vmnet.
2013-06-27T13:24:02.664+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Extracting the sources of the vmnet module.
2013-06-27T13:24:02.690+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module with command: /usr/bin/make -j -C /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only auto-build SUPPORT_SMP=1 HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/3.5.0-34-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc GREP=/usr/bin/make IS_GCC_3=no VMCCVER=4.6
2013-06-27T13:24:04.544+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Failed to compile module vmnet!
2013-06-27T13:24:04.550+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.5.0-34-generic.
2013-06-27T13:24:04.550+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/3.5.0-34-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.5.0-34-generic
2013-06-27T13:24:04.553+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2013-06-27T13:24:04.564+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2013-06-27T13:24:04.577+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Header path /lib/modules/3.5.0-34-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.5.0-34-generic is valid.
2013-06-27T13:24:04.577+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module vmblock.
2013-06-27T13:24:04.577+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Extracting the sources of the vmblock module.
2013-06-27T13:24:04.605+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module with command: /usr/bin/make -j -C /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmblock-only auto-build SUPPORT_SMP=1 HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/3.5.0-34-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc GREP=/usr/bin/make IS_GCC_3=no VMCCVER=4.6
2013-06-27T13:24:05.647+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Failed to compile module vmblock!
2013-06-27T13:24:05.652+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.5.0-34-generic.
2013-06-27T13:24:05.652+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/3.5.0-34-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.5.0-34-generic
2013-06-27T13:24:05.654+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2013-06-27T13:24:05.665+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2013-06-27T13:24:05.680+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Header path /lib/modules/3.5.0-34-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.5.0-34-generic is valid.
2013-06-27T13:24:05.680+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module vmci.
2013-06-27T13:24:05.680+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Extracting the sources of the vmci module.
2013-06-27T13:24:05.714+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module with command: /usr/bin/make -j -C /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only auto-build SUPPORT_SMP=1 HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/3.5.0-34-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc GREP=/usr/bin/make IS_GCC_3=no VMCCVER=4.6
2013-06-27T13:24:07.055+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Installing module vmci from /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci.o to /lib/modules/3.5.0-34-generic/misc.
2013-06-27T13:24:07.055+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Registering file: /usr/lib/vmware-installer/2.0/vmware-installer --register-file vmware-vmx regular /lib/modules/3.5.0-34-generic/misc/vmci.ko
2013-06-27T13:24:07.866+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.5.0-34-generic.
2013-06-27T13:24:07.866+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/3.5.0-34-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.5.0-34-generic
2013-06-27T13:24:07.869+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2013-06-27T13:24:07.881+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.6
2013-06-27T13:24:07.895+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Header path /lib/modules/3.5.0-34-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.5.0-34-generic is valid.
2013-06-27T13:24:07.895+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module vmci.
2013-06-27T13:24:07.895+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Extracting the sources of the vmci module.
2013-06-27T13:24:07.904+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module with command: /usr/bin/make -j -C /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only auto-build SUPPORT_SMP=1 HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/3.5.0-34-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc GREP=/usr/bin/make IS_GCC_3=no VMCCVER=4.6
2013-06-27T13:24:09.651+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module vsock.
2013-06-27T13:24:09.651+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Extracting the sources of the vsock module.
2013-06-27T13:24:09.688+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module with command: /usr/bin/make -j -C /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vsock-only auto-build SUPPORT_SMP=1 HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/3.5.0-34-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc GREP=/usr/bin/make IS_GCC_3=no VMCCVER=4.6
2013-06-27T13:24:11.402+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Installing module vsock from /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vsock.o to /lib/modules/3.5.0-34-generic/misc.
2013-06-27T13:24:11.403+01:00| vthread-3| I120: Registering file: /usr/lib/vmware-installer/2.0/vmware-installer --register-file vmware-vmx regular /lib/modules/3.5.0-34-generic/misc/vsock.ko
```

What am i missing?

Comment: There are issues with VMWare Workstation and the 3.X series of kernels. Google around for more details. I haven't been able to get everything working satisfactorily myself, but my situation is different from yours (running Fedora inside VM on OSX) so you may be able to find some help...

Comment: @MattDMo Yeah, i solved it by downgrading kernel from 3.5 to 3.2 and it worked :)

Answer (score -1):

I solved this issue with install these patches
https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules